# How to unzip a Reqwest/Hyper response using streams?

Tags: rust, reqwest

I need to download a 60MB ZIP file and extract the only file that comes within it. I want to download it and extract it using streams. How can I achieve this using Rust?

```
fn main () {
    let mut res = reqwest::get("myfile.zip").unwrap();
    // extract the response body to myfile.txt
}
```

In Node.js I would do something like this:

```
http.get('myfile.zip', response => {
  response.pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', entry => {
    if (entry.path.endsWith('.txt')) {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myfile.txt'))
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at the crate zip? https://github.com/mvdnes/zip-rs

Comment: I did, but I am just getting started with rust and reqwest + zip example would really come in handy.

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

Answer (score 5):

With [`reqwest`](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) you can get the `.zip` file:

```
reqwest::get("myfile.zip")
```

Since `reqwest` can only be used for retrieving the file, [`ZipArchive`](http://mvdnes.github.io/rust-docs/zip-rs/zip/read/struct.ZipArchive.html) from the [`zip`](https://crates.io/crates/zip) crate can be used for unpacking it. It's not possible to stream the `.zip` file into `ZipArchive`, since [`ZipArchive::new(reader: R)`](http://mvdnes.github.io/rust-docs/zip-rs/zip/read/struct.ZipArchive.html#method.new) requires `R` to implement [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) (which is fulfilled by the [`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.8.5/reqwest/struct.Response.html) of `reqwest`) and [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html), which is not implemented by `Response`.

As a workaround you may use a temporary file:

```
copy_to(&mut tmpfile)
```

As [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) implements both `Seek` and `Read`, [`zip`](https://crates.io/crates/zip) can be used here:

```
zip::ZipArchive::new(tmpfile)
```

This is a working example of the described method:

```
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate tempfile;
extern crate zip;

use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut tmpfile = tempfile::tempfile().unwrap();
    reqwest::get("myfile.zip").unwrap().copy_to(&mut tmpfile);
    let mut zip = zip::ZipArchive::new(tmpfile).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", zip);
}
```

[`tempfile`](https://crates.io/crates/tempfile) is a handy crate, which lets you create a temporary file, so you don't have to think of a name.

Answer (score 3):

That's how I'd read the file *hello.txt* with content `hello world` from the archive *hello.zip* located on a local server:

```
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate zip;

use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut res = reqwest::get("http://localhost:8000/hello.zip").unwrap();

    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let _ = res.read_to_end(&mut buf);

    let reader = std::io::Cursor::new(buf);
    let mut zip = zip::ZipArchive::new(reader).unwrap();

    let mut file_zip = zip.by_name("hello.txt").unwrap();
    let mut file_buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let _ = file_zip.read_to_end(&mut file_buf);

    let content = String::from_utf8(file_buf).unwrap();

    println!("{}", content);
}
```

This will output `hello world`

Comment: Is this example reading the entire file into a buffer? Have in mind that is a big file.

Comment: You could use `read` and fixed size buffers to read chunk by chunk. See this page for more information on `Read`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html

Answer (score 2):

#### `async` solution using Tokio

It's a bit convoluted, but you can do this using `tokio`, `futures`, [`tokio_util::compat`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/latest/tokio_util/compat/index.html) and [`async_compression`](https://docs.rs/async-compression/latest/async_compression/). The key is to create a `futures::io::AsyncRead` stream using `.into_async_read()` and then convert it into a `tokio::io::AsyncRead` using `.compat()`.

For simplicity, it downloads a `txt.gz` file and prints it line by line.

```rust
use async_compression::tokio::bufread::GzipDecoder;
use futures::stream::TryStreamExt;
use tokio::io::AsyncBufReadExt;
use tokio_util::compat::FuturesAsyncReadCompatExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let url = "https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/korteur/hello-world.txt.gz";
    let response = reqwest::get(url).await?;
    let stream = response
        .bytes_stream()
        .map_err(|e| futures::io::Error::new(futures::io::ErrorKind::Other, e))
        .into_async_read()
        .compat();
    let gzip_decoder = GzipDecoder::new(stream);

    // Print decompressed txt content
    let buf_reader = tokio::io::BufReader::new(gzip_decoder);
    let mut lines = buf_reader.lines();
    while let Some(line) = lines.next_line().await? {
        println!("{line}");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Credit to [Benjamin Kay](https://github.com/benkay86/async-applied/blob/master/reqwest-tokio-compat/src/main.rs).